# how to set the dropdownlist selected value

Tags: asp.net

work on C# asp.net vs05 .I have a ddl,ddl contain five element

```
ddl values are 
1
2
3
4
5
```

From the database i get 1,Need to show **selected value is 1** .How to show ddl Selected value is 1.

Comment: As the initial value in the ddl or after selecting the first item in the ddl?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set ddl.SelectedValue to the value of the item you want to select. If that doesn't work try this (where you replace 0 with the index of the element you need to select):

```
ddl.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about .SelectedValue property?

[MSDN, DropDownList class members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_members.aspx)